# _IO_wide_data_2: what's this?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb

I'm working on an embedded platform (architecture is [SH4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SuperH#SH-4)), and my program crashed a few minutes ago with a SIGABRT.

Luckily, I was running under gdbserver, and the thread that was interrupted by this signal has this stack dump:

```
#0  0x2a7f1678 in raise () from /home/[user]/target/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x2a7f2a4c in abort () from /home/[user]/target/lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x2a81ade0 in __libc_message () from /home/[user]/target/lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x2a81f3a8 in malloc_printerr () from /home/[user]/target/lib/libc.so.6
#4  0x2a8c3700 in _IO_wide_data_2 () from /home/[user]/target/lib/libc.so.6
```

Do you know what happened here? A bad free()? bad delete ? bad malloc?
What's "_IO_wide_data_2" supposed to do?
I see the malloc_printerr() call that I don't understand either.

Google gives me [234 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=_IO_wide_data_2) on this, but all of them are simply because the guys have that "function" in their backtrace.

Comment: That doesn't look like a full stack trace to me. Where's your function that called something from libc?

Comment: That's the problem, that's the only stack that will print, there's no function below that. The other threads have consistent stack trace, only this one is looking like that. I'll try to see if I still have the full trace!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A bad free()? bad delete ? bad malloc?

Yes I think it's one of these.

If the bug is easy reproducible, put a breakpoint in malloc.c, malloc_printerr. When debugger stops there, You'll probably get full call stack and find the buggy place in Your code. I still don't know why it happens, that after entering __libc_message, the call stack gets broken.

---

There is how I found this strange behaviour.
Simple app that deletes the same buffer twice:

```
void main()
{
    char * buf = new char[4*1024];
    delete[] buf;
    delete[] buf;
}
```

Inside malloc_printerr the call stack looks like this:

```
#0  malloc_printerr (action=3, str=0x297d0b5c "double free or corruption (top)", ptr=<value optimized out>) at malloc.c:5887
#1  0x29750be8 in __libc_free (mem=0x411008) at malloc.c:3622
#2  0x29612c70 in operator delete (ptr=<value optimized out>) at ../../../../libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/del_op.cc:49
#3  0x29612cc2 in operator delete[] (ptr=<value optimized out>) at ../../../../libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/del_opv.cc:37
#4  0x0040068a in main (argc=1, argv=0x7bb26814) at double_free.cpp:47
```

After entering __libc_message:

```
#0  __libc_message (do_abort=2, fmt=0x297d09c8 "*** glibc detected *** %s: %s: 0x%s *** ") at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/libc_fatal.c:50
#1  0x2974f3a8 in malloc_printerr (action=3, str=0x297d0b5c "double free or corruption (top)", ptr=<value optimized out>) at malloc.c:5887
#2  0x297f3700 in _IO_wide_data_2 () from /cygdrive/c/STM/SH4-Linux-gcc/opt/STM/STLinux2.3/devkit/sh4/target/lib/libc.so.6
Backtrace stopped: frame did not save the PC
```

Maybe it has something to do with **attribute**((noreturn)) and compiler optimization?

Comment: WOOOOOOWWWW, that's a big up for you, thanks! I stumbled again on this freaking issue today, and was stuck at the same level. Putting a break in malloc_err is the BEST!

Comment: I'll atually get your answer, because it's way more useful!

Answer (score 7):

It is a stream to `stderr` for wide character support.

You can break it down into various parts:

- `_IO` : Input/Output.
- `wide_data` : Wide data
- `2` : stderr

You also have;

`_IO_wide_data_0` : stdin
`_IO_wide_data_1` : stdout

They are chained as 2->1->0.

`malloc_printerr()` is used to print various error messages when there is something bad happening/caught in dynamic memory management. But your trace looks capped (have you removed anything?).

It could be a write to stderr where you try to write something not in memory, in corrupted memory, in …

Or it could be lower stack point causing write to stderr.

Or …

Comment: Ok, thanks for these precisions. I admit I didn't yet find the *reason* for this crash, but at least I know what the stack means :)

Comment: I'll take your answer, because it answers the question :) Although the bug is still here...

Comment: @Gui13; Thanks, tho I must admit I feel somewhat bad not have helped more. If you manage to squeeze more information from the crash please update. Have you checked syslog? __libc_message can have added some more info there.

Comment: We've run across this symbol in the course of debugging a crash, and it appears that multi-thread access to cout/cerr/stdout/stderr can overwrite this buffer space.

Answer (score 0):

Can you reproduce this error while running under GDB? You might get more stack trace information using the various "Stack" commands found here:

[GDB Cheat Sheet](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html)

You might need to move up or down a few stack frames to determine what happened.

Comment: I got this stack in GDB (as I said in the question), and all the other threads were in a thread-lock function (select, poll, condition-wait,...), so the faulty thread is the one with this stack. And this stack is all there is to see, there's no frame after #4 :/ This is what has been on my mind.